# How to describe essential elements of personnel policies

Tags: human-resources, canada

We are a small organization (<20 full time staff, <$10M revenue). Our Board is trying to onboard a new management team.

We want to formulate some short term goals for the next few months. One of the short term deliverables is to have an appropriate personnel policy and see to it followed.

How do we best describe the requirement in a general way that gives management the flexibility to compose policies that suits the organization's size and solves issues arising from practical workplace scenarios. Are there common features of personnel policies without which some problems are likely to arise?

The context is that our organization did at some point have a working set of personnel policies. But over the years, they stopped being followed and individual details stopped being understood. Now we are starting from scratch in a way but do have some of those resources from the past as well.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to expand on what you have here and let the new people do their job.

Clearly articulate:-

1. What you need done (Create a new personnel policy that people will understand and follow).
2. Why you need it done (What issues are a lack of policy causing you?).
3. What have you tried in the past (the previous policies)?
4. Why do you think it failed?

You want to give the new folk enough information without telling them what to do (or else why bother hiring them?!).

Good luck.